# Javascript object value changes automatically when saving to variable

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, base64, byte

I am working with the Ivanti Service Manager and am currently trying to transfer attachments to a third party system. For this I read the attachment from Ivanti. The following object is the result.

```
{"status":"Success","exceptionReason":null,"attachmentData":"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"}
```

The third party system expects a base64 string like attachmentData from the object. But as soon as I want to access the value of attachmentData and save it in a variable, it automatically becomes byte code. But what I need is the base64 code as it is already given in the response object. How do I get to the string without it being converted automatically? Thank you very much for your help.

ps: The problem in Ivanti is that I can't use all javascript methods because the system doesn't know them.

Comment: "it automatically becomes byte code" — what does that mean?

Comment: Sorry if it was inaccurate:
If I want to access the value via:
var AttachmentData = result.attachmentData;

The value of AttachmentData becomes [137.0,80.0,78.0,71.0,.....]

Comment: Try JSON.stringify(object) while saving. And while reading JSON.parse(object)

Comment: I'm afraid that didn't help either. Does anyone have another idea? I have to get a base64 string from this byte array somehow, as it is actually already in the initial result.

Comment: If you want base64 then you need to use a HTML "text" field. Detailed instructions and example can be found on my
[Ivanti Service Manager Blog](https://ivantiservicemanagerconsultant.wordpress.com/2020/08/05/how-to-embed-an-image-in-global-constants-and-business-object-fields-base64-html-getglobal-function-screenshot/)